# Badge count wrapping on badges page

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

There are enough people with the Popular Question badge for the count to wrap to a new line in Chrome.

[image: The wrapping in question]

Not a sure it's really a bug per se, but it still would look better if the cell was resized a little so it could be on the same line.

Comment: Completely agree, BTW I don't like the extra spacing produced by the two lined explanation of badges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an error in the html that got deployed. I have reverted that erroneous change.